# clock_gettime() is not giving correct outputs

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, time, multiprocessing

I am trying to calculate the effect of multi-threading on the run-time of matrix multiplication. It sequentially calculates the time-taken of the single-thread process, then "multi-processed" process and then multi-threaded process. My code calculating time is as follows:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
for (i = 0; i < arows; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < bcols; j++)
    if(pthread_create(&tids[i * bcols + j], NULL, &multi_thread_mul, (void*) &t_data[i * bcols + j]))
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
for (i = 0; i < threads; i++)
  pthread_join(tids[i],NULL);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
time_taken = ((double)((end.tv_nsec * 1e-3) - (start.tv_nsec * 1e-3)));
```

Only the nested loop part is paralyzed for latter processes.
I should report the time taken to execute in microseconds. It worked fine on input dimensions of 200 * 200, 500 * 500. But if the dimension of input goes like 2000 * 2000, it is giving the wrong time. I think it is not overflowing as the entire execution took about only 5 to 10 sec, which is order  10^7 us. (us stands for micro-seconds)
Sample outputs:

> Time taken for single threaded: 18446744073709499930 us
>
> Time taken for the multi process: 574915 us
>
> Time taken for multi-threaded: 140736432838816 us
>
> Speedup for multi-process : 32086037194558.33 x
>
> Speedup for multi-threaded : 131072.98 x

It is evident from the above output that it gave the right time taken for multi-process but did not other multi-thread and single-thread. I couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Hm, you do not take the `tv_sec` structure members into account at all; that does not look correct

Comment: The OS may interrupt your process for some other task(s).

Comment: Furthermore, better divide by `1000` instead of multiplying with `1e-3`, and avoid double here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code fails to account for `.tv_nsec` roll-over. [@Ctx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825162/clock-gettime-is-not-giving-correct-outputs/59826620#comment105787284_59825162)

When the subtraction below is negative, assigning to an unsigned 64-bit object results in a large number just under
18446744073709551616 or 2<sup>64</sup> such as
18446744073709499930.

```
//           sometimes this difference is negative due to second roll-over in .tv_sec
time_taken = ((double)((end.tv_nsec * 1e-3) - (start.tv_nsec * 1e-3)));
```

Instead consider

```
time_t tdiff = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
assert(tdiff >= 0);  // Time should march forward
#define nsec_per_sec 1000000000LL
#define nsec_in_a_usec 1000L
time_taken = (tdiff*nsec_per_sec + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/nsec_in_a_usec;
```